# Can I reopen a question?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

Yesterday I thought my question was answered, but it wasn't. Can I reopen [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551382/while-command-in-bash-if-theres-a-string-in-file-txt-do) so it can get more attention?

Comment: It isn't closed. What is the problem? Are you asking to have it bumped?

Comment: Yes please bump it

Comment: Ummm... no.... that isn't the way things are supposed to work... You left a message on the answer only 17 minutes ago, you need to give people time to respond.

Comment: If you edit the question, it jumps to the top again.

Comment: @Crazy_Bash: edit; and while you are at it, you may want to actually improve the OP so you will also improve the chances of more people responding better.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll do my best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not "closed" after any amount of time (unless excplicitely closed by voting / mod intervention).  If you don't get an answer that *you are satisfied with* in a  resonable amount of time (this varies depending on the question, but a day or so is probably reasonable) then editing with updates on your own personal progrees of working towards a solution is the best option.

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty):

> First, make sure you’ve asked a good question. 
>   To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. 
>   Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. 
>   Document your own continued 
>   efforts to answer your question. 
>   **This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.**